# gcc cross compile linker error: could not read symbols: File format not recognized collect2

Tags: gcc

I'm trying to cross compile a package applicaiton with gcc-eabi.  I have modified the configuration file to point to all the target directories.  But the linker still gives an error when linking some shared libraries.  The exact error is below:

```
Linking CXX shared library /home/aeodrs/JAUS++-2.110519-src/libraries/jaus++/2.0/lib   /libcxutils.so

/home/aeodrs/JAUS++-2.110519-src/libraries/jaus++/2.0/lib/libcxjpeg-6b.a: could not read symbols: File format not recognized collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

make[2]: *** [/home/aeodrs/JAUS++-2.110519-src/libraries/jaus++/2.0/lib/libcxutils.so] Error 1
make[1]: *** [libcxutils/CxUtils/libcxutils/CMakeFiles/cxutils.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
aeodrs@ubuntu:~/JAUS++-2.110519-src/libraries/jaus++/2.0/build/cmake$
```

I'm not sure why the linker can't read or is corrupting the library file.

Comment: did you modify LD as well as CC in the makefile? It seems that you're compiling with the cross-GCC but linking with your PC's ld.

Comment: Yes. I modified all the program variable in the makefile.

Comment: Solved by editing subMakefiles in project.  Thanks for all comments!

Comment: @Shaad, I'm facing a similar problem, please can you suggest me anything? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10756562/how-to-use-sdl-libraries-in-the-android-project-built-using-ffmpeg