# Cross compiling with static library using Eclipse CDT

Tags: eclipse-cdt, xively, beagleboneblack

While working with Xively C Library to cross-compile for Ubuntu on Beaglebone Black using Eclipse IDE, I encountered this error:

```
**** Build of configuration Debug for project Test ****

make all 
Building file: ../src/Test.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ -I/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.7.3 -I/home/nishant/libxively/src/libxively -I/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.7.3/bits -I/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.7.3/ext -I/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.7.3/arm-linux-gnueabi -I/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.7.3/backward -I/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.7.3/decimal -includexively.h -includexi_helpers.h -includexi_err.h -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/Test.d" -MT"src/Test.d" -o "src/Test.o" "../src/Test.cpp"
Finished building: ../src/Test.cpp

Building target: Test
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ -L/home/nishant/workspace/Test/src -L/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/lib -o "Test"  ./src/Test.o   -lxively
**/home/nishant/workspace/Test/src/libxively.a: could not read symbols: File format not recognized
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Test] Error 1**

**** Build Finished ****
```

I think the problem is related to this:

- [gcc cross compile linker error: could not read symbols: File format not recognized collect2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10262974/gcc-cross-compile-linker-error-could-not-read-symbols-file-format-not-recogniz)

Answer (score 0):

/home/nishant/workspace/Test/src/libxively.a  is in a different format (likely x86).  Make sure libxively is built using the cross-compiler.
You may run into library dependencies problems, in which case it is simpler to build on the bbk instead of cross compiling.